# How can I pass multiple commits to a Cherry Pick API in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I do have a requirement where I need to create cherry pick only the specific list of commits instead of one commit and then raise a pull request from the temporary branch which Cherry Pick API creates for me. I didn't find any sample script to achieve. Can someone please help me ? I find the below code everywhere.

```
  $requestbody= @{
 "generatedRefName" = "refs/heads/sourcebranch";
 "ontoRefName" = "refs/heads/targetbranch";
 "repository" = @{
                "name"= $RepoName
                };
 "source" = @{
               "commitList"= @(
                 @{
                  "commitId" = "405d4e27a4ac33fcfc489076ae3b890571619483"
                  }
                 )
             } 
}
```

What I need is as below.

```
    $requestbody= @{
 "generatedRefName" = "refs/heads/sourcebranch";
 "ontoRefName" = "refs/heads/targetbranch";
 "repository" = @{
                "name"= $RepoName
                };
 "source" = @{
               "commitList"= @(
                pass multiple commits in this list
                 )
             } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple: commit list is just an array of `GitCommitRef`. That means you can use multiple commits like this:

```
source = @{
        commitList = @(
            @{
                commitId = '4a419de68788eeb8888c0d04513d48e01ed88a17'
            },
            @{
                commitId = '7feb89d53c155940b9c19ea2d683575865cba911'
            }
        )
    }
```

[More about powershell arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#the-array-sub-expression-operator)